# anyway to have a hotkey activate an application without AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, putty

I used to use Autohotkey to set up a key combination that launches an app or switches to it if already running.  Worked great, but at work, they're forcing me to use a locked down machine and won't let me install Autohotkey.  I really don't need all of the functionality of Autohotkey anyway - if there's a way to accomplish this 'launch or activate' behavior in powershell or elsewhere.

Windows used to do this when you assigned a hotkey to a regular shortcut, but somewhere along the line that broke.  Hotkeys in Windows shortcuts now launch a new copy every time (at least for PuTty - which is the app I'm trying to do this for).  I routinely run PuTty sessions on multiple different linux systems, and being able to switch between them with hotkeys is a godsend.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's possible to use Autohotkey without running the installer, so it works without admin privileges:

access/[intstructions here](https://www.thenickmay.com/how-to-install-autohotkey-even-without-administrator-access/)